# How can I start php-fpm in a Docker container by default?

Tags: php, docker, ansible

I have this Docker image -

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER Me <me.me>
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y git https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

RUN yum install -y ansible
RUN git clone https://github.com/.../dockerAnsible.git
RUN ansible-playbook dockerFileBootstrap.yml
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
EXPOSE 80 443 3306

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Basically, I want it so that php-fpm starts when the docker container starts.  I have php-fpm working if I manually go into the container and turn it on with `/usr/sbin/php-fpm`.

I tried it inside of my ansible file with this command (it didn't work).  I tried using the service module as well with no luck.-

```
 - name: Start php fpm
   command: /usr/sbin/php-fpm
```

How can I have php-fpm running along with apache?

Comment: Add a `RUN /usr/sbin/php-fpm`?

Comment: No dice.  It still does not start once the container is started using this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use `supervisor` in order to launch several services

In your dockerfile, install supervisor, then you launch

```
COPY ./docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
....
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```

And your `docker/supervisord.conf` contains all the services you want to start, so you can have something like that

```
[program:php-fpm]
  command=/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm -c /etc/php-fpm.conf
  ;command=/usr/sbin/php70-fpm -c /etc/php-fpm.d
  stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
  stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
  stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
  stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
  command=/usr/sbin/nginx
  stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
  stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
  stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
  stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Of course you should adapt with your path and php-fpm versions and your services (nginx in my example, apache for you etc...), but basically supervisor is the best way to manage the start of several services from one start point.

Here you can find the official doc of docker about supervisor

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/

Comment: While this method seems like it would work, it seems like overkill for just the one extra service that I need to start.  Is it possible to do something like chain my CMD's together, or start it when the Docker container is being initialized?

Comment: Another option is to run php-fpm in another container and put the two containers on the same network. Then point the php-fpm httpd config at the other container.

Comment: I don't really find this method overkill, supervisor is a common way to handle multi processors management and the recommended way by docker, its only your docker file that will change a bit and one more config file. Your container will be more flexible if you want to add some services later. But if you find a easier "legit" method, please let us know, i'm interested

Comment: Suggesting adding another layer of complexity is not a good answer. Downvoting.

Comment: We should consider that nowadays containers are indeed designed for a single service. From that perspective, this answer is legit.

Comment: I like `supervisord` approach. It is THE way to handle situations like this.

Comment: This is an insane amount of configuration just to start a single service that starts automatically on non-Docker machines.

Answer (score 27):

I came here looking for how to run `php-fpm` in the foreground so it could be PID 1 in a docker container.  The solution is

```
php-fpm -F -R
```

## Explanation

We can check the available options with `php-fpm --help`

```
-F, --nodaemonize 
      force to stay in foreground, and ignore daemonize option from config file
```

If you are running `php-fpm` in a docker container, there is a good chance you are running the process as root.  php-fpm won't start as root without an extra flag:

```
  -R, --allow-to-run-as-root
        Allow pool to run as root (disabled by default)
```

Comment: Hi, is it safe to run php-fpm as root ? I'm worry

Comment: This answer only applies to running php-fpm inside a containerized environment. 
 If you are not using docker or some other container, running php-fpm as root greatly increases your exposure to hackers.

Comment: This command doesn't work in a Dockerfile, which is the use case for this answer.

Comment: I used this at the end of a bash startup script so I could do a lot of custom configuration. The -R is a bit scary though. If you're working off the official base image it should be ran as www-data.

Answer (score 18):

I needed similar thing recently. For **alpine** linux images it sufficed to run both `php-fpm` and a web server as the container command. Defined in `Dockerfile` somewhat like this:

```
CMD /usr/bin/php-fpm -D; nginx
```

ie. to daemonize `php-fpm` and then run `nginx` in foreground.

On **ubuntu/debian** images there is also necessary to *allow* starting recently installed packages by running a `Dockerfile` `RUN` command like this:

```
RUN echo "exit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
```

and then restart the `php-fpm` within a `CMD` command

```
CMD /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

More on `policy-rc.d` to be found [in this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365911/why-the-services-do-not-start-at-installation)

Comment: My plain simple friend, the 3rd one worked perfectly. Thanks. :-)

Comment: that first line worked like a charm, thanks, saved me the hassle of using supervisor.

Answer (score 3):

You may find this config useful if you'd like to run `php-fpm` and `Apache` (usually using MPM Event) in the same container:

```
[supervisord]

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm -F -R
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:apachectl]
command=apachectl -D "FOREGROUND" -k start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on Docker running Ubuntu 20.04 with nginx and php-fpm.

```
CMD /etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm start -F && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

No supervisors or cron jobs are required.

Comment: I would also suggest make an `ARG phpver=7.4` and then make it more general like this `RUN cp  /etc/init.d/php${phpver}-fpm /etc/init.d/php-fpm`. Then you add `CMD /etc/init.d/php-fpm start -F && nginx -g "daemon off;"`. In future you can change the php version from the ARG line.

Answer (score 1):

I use rc.local to start services inside a container, and then run a command inside that container to execute rc.local.  So here's a sample run command:

```
sudo docker run --restart=always -itd --name mycontainer -p 80:80 -p 443:443 myimage/name /bin/bash -c "/etc/rc.local && while true; do echo hello world; sleep 100; done"
```

And this is one of the rc.local files from /etc

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sleep 5
service mysql start
sleep 5
service php5-fpm start
sleep 5
service nginx start
exit 0
```

What this does is launch a container called "mycontainer" using the image "myimage/name" with ports 80 and 443 exposed.  Once launched it calls mysql, php5-fpm, and nginx to start up, pausing between each for 5 seconds.  In this manner you can call any service to start that you would want to run inside that container.  Remember to add open ports for those services though.

This run command will also append "Hello World" into your log file every 100 seconds as a "pulse" that will let you know when it was running and when it was stopped.

Answer (score 1):

I believe @ckeeney's answer above could be accepted as the correct answer but I was unable to get it working with my particular case.

#### use dumb-init

I have been able to proxy PID1 through dumb-init, and daemonize PHP-FPM with the following command : `dumb-init /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.2 -F -R`
https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/01/dumb-init-an-init-for-docker.html