# How to run apt php as non root user on official docker php image

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to run as non root my php-fm ubuntu:20.04 but i can't.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ARG TZ=Europe/Paris

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime && echo ${TZ} > /etc/timezone \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get -y install php-apcu \
    php-bz2 \
    php-cas \
    php-cli \
    php-curl \
    php-fpm \
    php-gd \
    php-imap \
    php-intl \
    php-json \
    php-ldap \
    php-mbstring \
    php-memcache \
    php-mysql \
    php-pear \
    php-pspell \
    php-tidy \
    php-xml \
    php-xmlrpc \
    php-xsl \
    php-zip \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

COPY www.conf /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

CMD /etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm start \
&& bash
```

Do you know how to do this on ubuntu or on official docker php image ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many similiar questions like this on SO already, this may help:

[Switching users inside Docker image to a non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549746/switching-users-inside-docker-image-to-a-non-root-user)

The Dockerfile reference for the USER directive is also quite handy, and should get you going:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

**Edit:**

From your responses, and further reading the Dockerfile, it seems like this is perhaps not quite the underlying issue you're trying to resolve

It's worth noting that php-fpm is a daemon and will not hold the container open if it dissapears to the background, I think you may have tried to mitigate this by adding `&& bash` but bash will exit if it does not receive input.

It could be well worth using something like `supervisord` which allows you to define processes to start at the beginning of the container. It will also let you start a web server in your container that can talk nicely to fpm:
[How can I start php-fpm in a Docker container by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313780/how-can-i-start-php-fpm-in-a-docker-container-by-default/44409813)

Comment: Yes, but my user can't start the deamon php-fpm with CMD. I don't know which permission i can change. And with official php docker image is difficult to install the extension.

Comment: It would be useful to explain what you did, and what behaviour you are seeing (`docker run` output, nothing at all, etc).

Have you encountered the docker-php-ext-install utilities provided by the default php images? They could perhaps help with installing php extenstions:
https://hub.docker.com/_/php

I've added a small note about using supervisor to my original answer, perhaps it will help you in keeping the running process open, I'm afraid I had to guess at your issue since the current behavior isn't clear